# Looking for an encrypted wifi extender

Tags: wifi

Looking for a powerful wifi extender (1200Mbps) that will encrypt my data.

Is there such an animal?

Hope you can help!

Thanks.

Comment: If you have encryption on your router, you *don't* need encryption on the extender.

Comment: All WiFi devices support encryption. It is enabled by putting a password on your WiFi network. The extender will connect to your WiFi using WPS and extend your WiFi with encryption exactly as it is configured on the router.